# .click() doesn't renew button state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to write a quiz, but once an answer is correct, the button of that answer is also shown to be correct when there's another question. I've tried everything to fix it but I just don't have a clue what the problem is.

**JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/bz6v5nbv/1/**

Bug reconstruction: Take answer C (correct) at the first question and again C (this time it's actually B) at the second one. Even though B would be correct, C is green, when clicked.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

var q = [];

q[1] = [3, "1", "Musik", "Welches Hotel ist sehr musikalisch?", "Hotel California", 
            "Riu Hotel", "Tokio Hotel", "Hotel Mama"];
q[2] = [2, "1", "Musik", "Was sitzt in einer Konservendose, singt und liest Nachrichten vor?", 
            "ein Schwammoli", "ein Radioli", "ein Tivoli", "ein Tivoli"];
q[3] = [4, "1", "Musik", "dd", 
            "ein Schwammoli", "ein Radioli", "ein Tivoli", "ein Tivoli"];

var fill = function( data ) {
    //buttons get filled with data from the array
    $( "#number" ).html( data[1]);
    $( "#cat" ).html( data[2]);
    $( "#ques span" ).html( data[3]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(1) button" ).html( data[4]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(2) button" ).html( data[5]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(3) button" ).html( data[6]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(4) button" ).html( data[7]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(" + data[0] + ") button" ).attr( "data-state", "true" );

    //images are set, depending on the true/false state of the button
    $( "#answ .answ button" ).each( function() {
        $( this ).click( function() {
            var button = $(this);
            $(this).css( "background-image", "url(images/btnBgLogged.png)" );
            $(this).css( "border-image-source", "url(images/btnLogged.png)" );
            button.click( function() {
                if ( button.data( "state" ) == true ) {
                    button.css( "background-image", "url(images/btnBgTrue.png)" );
                    button.css( "border-image-source", "url(images/btnTrue.png)" );
                } else {
                    button.css( "background-image", "url(images/btnBgFalse.png)" );
                    button.css( "border-image-source", "url(images/btnFalse.png)" );
                }
                setTimeout( next, 3000 );
            });
        });
    })

}   

var clear = function() {
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(1) button" ).removeAttr( "style" );
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(2) button" ).removeAttr( "style" );
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(3) button" ).removeAttr( "style" );
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(4) button" ).removeAttr( "style" );
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(1) button" ).removeAttr( "data-state" );
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(2) button" ).removeAttr( "data-state" );
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(3) button" ).removeAttr( "data-state" );
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(4) button" ).removeAttr( "data-state" );
}

var count = 1;
function next() {
    clear();
    fill( q[count] );
    count++;
}

next();

});
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle link seems to not working properly, can you fix it to help you?

Comment: You've described what behaviour you're trying to avoid but you forgot to describe the behaviour you want. Either way, binding a new click handler on every click is *probably not what you wanted*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there are multiple problems in your code. First of all, **it's not a matter of binding and unbinding events**, **it's a problem of rebinding a new click event each time you call your fill method**, you should extract your click listener from this function. conception problem :)

You also shouldn't check the presence of data-state, but instead you should check its value, more efficient.

```
    $( document ).ready( function() {

    var q = [];

    q[1] = [3, "1", "Musik", "Welches Hotel ist sehr musikalisch?", "Hotel California", 
                "Riu Hotel", "Tokio Hotel", "Hotel Mama"];
    q[2] = [2, "1", "Musik", "Was sitzt in einer Konservendose, singt und liest Nachrichten vor?", 
                "ein Schwammoli", "ein Radioli", "ein Tivoli", "ein Tivoli"];
    q[3] = [4, "1", "Musik", "dd", 
                "ein Schwammoli", "ein Radioli", "ein Tivoli", "ein Tivoli"];

    var fill = function( data ) {
        $( "#number" ).html( data[1]);
        $( "#cat" ).html( data[2]);
        $( "#ques span" ).html( data[3]);
        $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(1) button" ).html( data[4]);
        $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(2) button" ).html( data[5]);
        $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(3) button" ).html( data[6]);
        $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(4) button" ).html( data[7]);
        $( "#answ .answ button" ).attr( "data-state", "0" );
        $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(" + data[0] + ") button" ).attr( "data-state", "1" );
    }   



    var clear = function() {
        $( "#answ .answ button" ).removeAttr( "class" );
        $( "#answ .answ button" ).removeAttr( "data-state" );
    }

    var count = 1;
    function next() {
        clear();
        fill( q[count] );
        count++;
    }

    next();



    $( "#answ" ).on('click', '.answ button', function(){
        var button = $(this);
        console.log(button.attr( "data-state" ));
        if(button.hasClass('clicked')){
            newClass = ( 1 == button.attr( "data-state" ) )  ? 'good' : 'bad';

            button.removeClass('clicked').addClass(newClass);            
            setTimeout( next, 3000 );
        }
        else {
            button.addClass('clicked');  
        }
    });

});
```

[**Working demo here :)**](http://jsfiddle.net/bz6v5nbv/7/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one question left: Is this
`newClass = ( 1 == button.attr( "data-state" ) )  ? 'good' : 'bad';`
some kind of if-statement?

Comment: Note that in your next() function, you should check if count is not out of range for your q array ;)

Comment: @SimonMathewson It's definitely an if statement, ternary. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 2):

You do not unbind the events so you keep adding events to the button. So you can either call off when you run the clear() method or you can just unbind it right before you add the click.

```
$( this ).off("click").on("click", function() { ... }
```

and

```
button.off("click").on("click", function() { ... });
```

Comment: thanks, but the bug, as described above, still exists

Answer (score 1):

You should use [jquery .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of .click it is appropriate for binding dynamic element like:

```
$('#answ').on('click', 'button', function() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 29 should read

```
if ( button.attr( "data-state" ) == "true" ) {
```

[check the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz6v5nbv/5/)

The others have a point though, you are creating listeners for the click handler over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( this ).click( function() {
// replace with
$( this ).on('click'
```

and you dont need this:

```
button.click( function() {
```

since you already applyed click event on all buttons

I've set you comments in code for this fix on JSFiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/Lhu7poqu/
```

Now you have click once, after adding new background and waiting for re-rendering new question, all button events are unbinded and added again on next question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, but the bug, as described above, still exists

Comment: Try now, 
I've missed line 28.

You tryed to get data-state value from button with .data,
now is changed to .attr('data-state') and returns string "true"

Comment: `$( this ).click( function() {`
// replace with
`$( this ).on('click'` That code is 100% the same